# How do I access text values from multiple child nodes? Only getting values from first child node instance

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child

I've inherited a fairly ugly xsl script and have very limited experience with xslt. I was helped a lot from you guys yesterday but still struggling a bit so I'm providing the whole xml and better description of wanted output.

I assume it's something stupid being done by wrapping the whole script in a template and a choose because I keep getting compile errors when I make suggested changes and because I'm flying a bit blind it's clear to me I lack sufficient understanding and time to acquire it so I would sincerely appreciate some help.

At this stage I am only concerned with **component 4**. Once I nut it out I'm sure I will be able to rewrite the rest of the script.

Output I am getting;

```
contactID,mediumCode,areaCode,communicationDetails
"0123456789","T","02","62881111"
"5290001890","T","02","92881781"
"4400139361","T","07","49281771"
"6600027368","T","07","48103280"
```

Output I need;

```
contactID,mediumCode,areaCode,communicationDetails
"0123456789","T","02","62881111"
"5290001890","T","02","92881781"
"4400139361","T","07","49281771"
"6600027368","T","07","48103280"

"0123456789","E","","john.smith@myisp.com.au"
"5290001890","E","","rabina.smiley@ekit.com.au"
"4400139361","E","","suzanne.jones2@optus.com"
"6600027368","E","","maryann.smart@dodo.com"

"0123456789","M","","04140012225"
"5290001890","M","","04290012333"
"4400139361","M","","0404009266"
"6600027368","M","","0414003242"
```

XSL stylesheet:

```
<!-- AHPRA XML CSV Converter Script -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- BATCH FILE COMPONENT -->
<xsl:param name="component"/>
<!-- 0=requestHeader, 1=personalDetails, 2=residencyDetails, 3=addressDetails, 4=communications, 5=primaryQualification, 6=additionalQualifications, 7=legacyDetails, 8=registrationDetails, 9=specialtyDetails, 10=conditionDetails, 11=endorsementDetails, 12=undertakingDetails, 13=notationDetails, 14=employmentDetails -->

<!-- FORMAT DATE -->
<xsl:template name="formatDate">
  <xsl:param name="date"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="boolean($date)">
      <xsl:if test="string-length($date)&gt;0">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($date,9,2),'/',substring($date,6,2),'/',substring($date,1,4))" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- NL2BR -->
<xsl:template name="nl2br">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($string,'&#10;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '&#10;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <br/>
      <xsl:call-template name="nl2br"><xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,'&#10;')"/></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="$string" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>

    <!-- COMPONENT 0 requestHeader -->
    <!-- runType, dateStamp, sequenceNumber -->
    <xsl:when test="$component=0">
      <xsl:for-each select="medicare">
        "<xsl:value-of select="requestHeader/runType" />",
        <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
          <xsl:with-param name="date" select="requestHeader/dateStamp"/>
        </xsl:call-template>,
        "<xsl:value-of select="requestHeader/sequenceNumber" />
        "<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- COMPONENT 1 personalDetails -->
    <!-- contactID, givenName, middleName, familyName, title, gender, dateOfBirth, dobAccuracy, dateOfDeath -->
    <xsl:when test="$component=1">
      <xsl:for-each select="//person">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(concat(personalDetails/givenName,personalDetails/middleName,personalDetails/familyName,personalDetails/title,personalDetails/gender,personalDetails/dateOfBirth,personalDetails/dobAccuracy,personalDetails/dateOfDeath))!=0">
          "<xsl:value-of select="contactID" />",
          "<xsl:value-of select="personalDetails/givenName" />",
          "<xsl:value-of select="personalDetails/middleName" />",
          "<xsl:value-of select="personalDetails/familyName" />",
          "<xsl:value-of select="personalDetails/title" />",
          "<xsl:value-of select="personalDetails/gender" />",
          <xsl:call-template name="formatDate"><xsl:with-param name="date" select="personalDetails/dateOfBirth"/></xsl:call-template>,
          "<xsl:value-of select="personalDetails/dobAccuracy" />",
          <xsl:call-template name="formatDate"><xsl:with-param name="date" select="personalDetails/dateOfDeath"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- COMPONENT 4 communications -->
    <!-- contactID, mediumCode, areaCode, communicationDetails -->

    <xsl:variable name="q" select="'&quot;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="', '" />

    <xsl:when test="$component=4">
      <xsl:for-each select="//person">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(concat(communications/communication/mediumCode,communications/communication/areaCode,communications/communication/communicationDetails))!=0">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($q, contactID, $q, $c, $q, 
          normalize-space(communications/communication/mediumCode), $q, $c, $q, 
          normalize-space(communications/communication/areaCode), $q, $c, $q, 
          normalize-space(communications/communication/communicationDetails), $q)" />
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML data:

```
<medicare>  
  <requestHeader>
    <runType>O</runType>
    <dateStamp>2011-05-30</dateStamp>
    <sequenceNumber>10</sequenceNumber>
  </requestHeader>
  <person>
    <contactID>0123456789</contactID>
    <personalDetails>
      <givenName>John</givenName>
      <middleName>Alan</middleName>
      <familyName>Smith</familyName>
      <title>DR</title>
      <gender>M</gender>
      <dateOfBirth>1932-03-10</dateOfBirth>      
      <dobAccuracy>AAA</dobAccuracy>
      <dateOfDeath>1932-03-11</dateOfDeath>
    </personalDetails>
    <residencyDetails>
      <residencyStatus>Permanent Resident</residencyStatus>
      <visaType>Temporary</visaType>
      <passportNum>F1925190</passportNum>
      <countryOfIssue>Australia</countryOfIssue>
    </residencyDetails>
    <addressDetails>
      <address>
      <addressPurposeIndicator>Preferred Address</addressPurposeIndicator>
      <floorLevelNum>10</floorLevelNum>
    <floorLevelType>Ground</floorLevelType>
    <lotNum>72</lotNum>
        <postcode>2000</postcode>
        <state>NSW</state>
        <streetName>Main</streetName>
        <streetNum>112</streetNum>
        <streetType>RD</streetType>
        <locality>SYDNEY</locality>
        <flatUnitNum>3</flatUnitNum>
    <flatUnitType>Unit</flatUnitType>
        <sitePremisesName>St Vincents</sitePremisesName>
      </address>
      <address>
        <addressPurposeIndicator>Principle Place of Practice</addressPurposeIndicator>
        <floorLevelNum />
    <floorLevelType />
    <lotNum />
        <postcode>2000</postcode>
        <state>NSW</state>
        <streetName>Station</streetName>
        <streetNum />
        <streetType>ST</streetType>
        <locality>SYDNEY</locality>
        <flatUnitNum />
    <flatUnitType />
        <sitePremisesName>North Shore Hospital</sitePremisesName>
      </address>
    </addressDetails>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>02</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>62881111</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>john.smith@myisp.com.au</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>04140012225</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
    <registrationDetails>
       <registration>
          <registrationID>MED0000000009</registrationID>
          <profession>Medical Practitioner</profession>
          <division />
          <initialRegistrationStartDate>1977-08-03</initialRegistrationStartDate>
          <registrationType>General</registrationType>
          <registrationSubType />
          <registrationTypeStartDate>2011-04-30</registrationTypeStartDate>
          <registrationStatus>Registered</registrationStatus>
          <registrationStatusStartDate>2011-05-30</registrationStatusStartDate>
          <specialtyDetails>
            <specialtyDetail>
               <specialty>Heart Bypass</specialty>
               <fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>Surgery</fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>
           <specialtyPracticeStartDate>2010-02-20</specialtyPracticeStartDate>
           <specialtyPracticeEndDate>2011-04-23</specialtyPracticeEndDate>
            </specialtyDetail>
          </specialtyDetails>
          <conditionDetails>
            <condition>
               <applicationRegistrationCondition>APPROVED</applicationRegistrationCondition>
               <conditionApprovedDate>1805-12-08</conditionApprovedDate>
               <conditionDetail>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</conditionDetail>
            </condition>
        </conditionDetails>
        <endorsementDetails>
          <endorsement>
               <endorsementType>Medicine Man</endorsementType>
               <endorsementSubType>Voodoo</endorsementSubType>
               <endorsementCreateDate>2002-08-20</endorsementCreateDate>
               <endorsementEndDate>2017-06-06</endorsementEndDate>
          </endorsement>
        </endorsementDetails>
        <undertakingDetails>
          <undertaking>
               <undertakingType>Further Study</undertakingType>
               <undertakingApprovedDate>2001-07-11</undertakingApprovedDate>
               <undertakingText>The Doctor will undertake further study.</undertakingText>
          </undertaking>
        </undertakingDetails>
          <notationDetails>
            <notationDetail>
               <notationCreateDate />  
               <notationEndDate />  
           <notation />
            </notationDetail>
          </notationDetails>
        </registration>
        <registration>
          <registrationID>MED0000000010</registrationID>
          <profession>Medical Practitioner</profession>
          <division />
          <initialRegistrationStartDate>1977-08-03</initialRegistrationStartDate>
          <registrationType>Specialist</registrationType>
          <registrationSubType />
          <registrationTypeStartDate>2011-04-30</registrationTypeStartDate>
          <registrationStatus>Registered</registrationStatus>
          <registrationStatusStartDate>2011-05-30</registrationStatusStartDate>
          <specialtyDetails>
            <specialtyDetail>
               <specialty>Pathology</specialty>
               <fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>General pathology</fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>
           <specialtyPracticeStartDate>2010-11-01</specialtyPracticeStartDate>
           <specialtyPracticeEndDate />
            </specialtyDetail>
          </specialtyDetails>
          <conditionDetails>
            <condition>
               <applicationRegistrationCondition>APPROVED</applicationRegistrationCondition>
               <conditionApprovedDate>1805-12-08</conditionApprovedDate>
               <conditionDetail>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</conditionDetail>
            </condition>
        </conditionDetails>
        <endorsementDetails>
          <endorsement>
               <endorsementType />
               <endorsementSubType />
               <endorsementCreateDate />
               <endorsementEndDate />
          </endorsement>
        </endorsementDetails>
        <undertakingDetails>
          <undertaking>
               <undertakingType></undertakingType>
               <undertakingApprovedDate></undertakingApprovedDate>
               <undertakingText></undertakingText>
          </undertaking>
        </undertakingDetails>
          <notationDetails>
            <notationDetail>
               <notationCreateDate />  
               <notationEndDate />  
           <notation />
            </notationDetail>
          </notationDetails>
       </registration>
    </registrationDetails>
    <employmentDetails>
      <positionTitle>Chief Medical Officer</positionTitle>
      <sponsorOrganisationName>North Shore Hospital</sponsorOrganisationName>
      <sponsorOrganisationContact>Peter Piper</sponsorOrganisationContact>
    </employmentDetails>
  </person>
  <person>
    <contactID>5290001890</contactID>
    <personalDetails>
      <givenName>Rabina</givenName>
      <middleName>Dora</middleName>
      <familyName>Smiley</familyName>
      <title>DR</title>
      <gender>F</gender>
      <dateOfBirth>1961-03-22</dateOfBirth>      
      <dobAccuracy>AAA</dobAccuracy>
      <dateOfDeath>1900-12-01</dateOfDeath>
    </personalDetails>
    <residencyDetails>
      <residencyStatus>Australian Citizen</residencyStatus>
      <visaType>Perm</visaType>
      <passportNum>P1234567</passportNum>
      <countryOfIssue>New Zealand</countryOfIssue>
    </residencyDetails>
    <addressDetails>
      <address>
        <addressPurposeIndicator>Both preferred and practice</addressPurposeIndicator>
        <floorLevelNum />
      <floorLevelType />
      <lotNum />
        <postcode>2040</postcode>
        <state>NSW</state>
        <streetName>Plenty</streetName>
        <streetNum>29</streetNum>
        <streetType>RD</streetType>
        <locality>LEICHHARDT</locality>
        <flatUnitNum />
      <flatUnitType />
        <sitePremisesName />
      </address>
    </addressDetails>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>02</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>92881781</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>rabina.smiley@ekit.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>04290012333</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
    <registrationDetails>
       <registration>
          <registrationID>MED0000000219</registrationID>
          <profession>Medical Practitioner</profession>
          <division />
          <initialRegistrationStartDate>2010-04-15</initialRegistrationStartDate>
          <registrationType>Limited</registrationType>
          <registrationSubType>Area of Need</registrationSubType>
          <registrationTypeStartDate>2010-05-20</registrationTypeStartDate>
          <registrationStatus>Surrendered</registrationStatus>
          <registrationStatusStartDate>2011-05-29</registrationStatusStartDate>
          <specialtyDetails>
            <specialtyDetail>
               <specialty>Delivering Babies</specialty>
               <fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>Midwifery</fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>
           <specialtyPracticeStartDate>2009-01-31</specialtyPracticeStartDate>
           <specialtyPracticeEndDate>2099-04-08</specialtyPracticeEndDate>
            </specialtyDetail>
          </specialtyDetails>
          <conditionDetails>
            <condition>
               <applicationRegistrationCondition>Area of Need</applicationRegistrationCondition>
               <conditionApprovedDate>2010-05-28</conditionApprovedDate>
               <conditionDetail>PRE AMC TRAINING - TO WORK WITHIN EMERGENCY AT LYELL MCEWIN HOSPITAL - UNDER SUPERVISION OF DR H BLAH, DR B BLOGS NOMINATED SUPERVISORS.</conditionDetail>
            </condition>
           <condition>
               <applicationRegistrationCondition>Area of Need</applicationRegistrationCondition>
               <conditionApprovedDate>2011-05-22</conditionApprovedDate>
               <conditionDetail>DR B BLOGS NOMINATED SUPERVISOR</conditionDetail>
            </condition>
        </conditionDetails>
        <endorsementDetails>
          <endorsement>
               <endorsementType />
               <endorsementSubType />
               <endorsementCreateDate />
               <endorsementEndDate />
          </endorsement>
        </endorsementDetails>
        <undertakingDetails>
          <undertaking>
               <undertakingType>University Lectures</undertakingType>
               <undertakingApprovedDate>2014-12-18</undertakingApprovedDate>
               <undertakingText>The Doctor will undertake to deliver lectures to uni students.</undertakingText>
          </undertaking>
        </undertakingDetails>
          <notationDetails>
            <notationDetail>
               <notationCreateDate>1980-09-11</notationCreateDate> 
               <notationEndDate>2016-09-11</notationEndDate>
           <notation>Ineligible Orderly</notation>
            </notationDetail>
          </notationDetails>
        </registration>
    </registrationDetails>
    <employmentDetails>
      <positionTitle>Dr Dre</positionTitle>
      <sponsorOrganisationName>Aftermath Hospital</sponsorOrganisationName>
      <sponsorOrganisationContact>Eminem</sponsorOrganisationContact>
    </employmentDetails>
  </person>
  <person>
    <contactID>4400139361</contactID>
    <personalDetails>
      <givenName>Suzanne</givenName>
      <middleName>Lillian</middleName>
      <familyName>Jones</familyName>
      <title>MS</title>
      <gender>F</gender>
      <dateOfBirth>1971-12-13</dateOfBirth>      
      <dobAccuracy>AAA</dobAccuracy>
      <dateOfDeath>1905-09-22</dateOfDeath>
    </personalDetails>
    <residencyDetails>
      <residencyStatus>Australian Citizen</residencyStatus>
      <visaType />
      <passportNum />
      <countryOfIssue />
    </residencyDetails>
    <addressDetails>
      <address>
        <addressPurposeIndicator>Both preferred and practice</addressPurposeIndicator>
        <floorLevelNum />
      <floorLevelType />
      <lotNum />
        <postcode>4740</postcode>
        <state>QLD</state>
        <streetName>The Avenue</streetName>
        <streetNum>419</streetNum>
        <streetType>ST</streetType>
        <locality>ANDERGROVE</locality>
        <flatUnitNum />
      <flatUnitType />
        <sitePremisesName />
      </address>
    </addressDetails>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>07</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>49281771</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>suzanne.jones2@optus.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>0404009266</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
    <registrationDetails>
       <registration>
          <registrationID>NMW0000003085</registrationID>
          <profession>Nurse</profession>
          <division>Registered Nurse (Division 1)</division>
          <initialRegistrationStartDate>1994-03-15</initialRegistrationStartDate>
          <registrationType>General</registrationType>
          <registrationSubType />
          <registrationTypeStartDate>1994-03-15</registrationTypeStartDate>
          <registrationStatus>Registered</registrationStatus>
          <registrationStatusStartDate>2011-05-27</registrationStatusStartDate>
          <specialtyDetails>
            <specialtyDetail>
               <specialty>Being Excellent</specialty>
               <fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>Excellence</fieldOfSpecialtyPractice>
           <specialtyPracticeStartDate>2008-05-29</specialtyPracticeStartDate>
           <specialtyPracticeEndDate>2018-11-15</specialtyPracticeEndDate>
            </specialtyDetail>
          </specialtyDetails>
          <conditionDetails>
            <condition>
               <applicationRegistrationCondition>REJECTED</applicationRegistrationCondition>
               <conditionApprovedDate>1805-04-08</conditionApprovedDate>
               <conditionDetail>The lazy dog jumped up to bite the fox.</conditionDetail>
            </condition>
        </conditionDetails>
        <endorsementDetails>
          <endorsement>
               <endorsementType>Nurse Practitioner</endorsementType>
               <endorsementSubType>Nurse</endorsementSubType>
               <endorsementCreateDate>2011-04-30</endorsementCreateDate>
               <endorsementEndDate />
          </endorsement>
        </endorsementDetails>
        <undertakingDetails>
          <undertaking>
               <undertakingType>Education</undertakingType>
               <undertakingApprovedDate>2011-05-01</undertakingApprovedDate>
               <undertakingText>The Doctor will undertake training in new Pathology methods.</undertakingText>
          </undertaking>
        </undertakingDetails>
          <notationDetails>
            <notationDetail>
               <notationCreateDate />  
               <notationEndDate />  
           <notation />
            </notationDetail>
          </notationDetails>
        </registration>
    </registrationDetails>
    <employmentDetails>
      <positionTitle />
      <sponsorOrganisationName />
      <sponsorOrganisationContact />
    </employmentDetails>
  </person>
  <person>
    <contactID>6600027368</contactID>
    <personalDetails>
      <givenName>Mary</givenName>
      <middleName>Ann</middleName>
      <familyName>Smart</familyName>
      <title>MRS</title>
      <gender>F</gender>
      <dateOfBirth>1970-10-03</dateOfBirth>      
      <dobAccuracy>AAA</dobAccuracy>
      <dateOfDeath />
    </personalDetails>
    <residencyDetails>
      <residencyStatus>Kiwi</residencyStatus>
      <visaType>Temp</visaType>
      <passportNum>K7777777</passportNum>
      <countryOfIssue>New Zealand</countryOfIssue>
    </residencyDetails>
    <addressDetails>
      <address>
        <addressPurposeIndicator>Both preferred and practice</addressPurposeIndicator>
        <floorLevelNum />
      <floorLevelType />
      <lotNum />
        <postcode>4214</postcode>
        <state>QLD</state>
        <streetName>The Terrace</streetName>
        <streetNum>39</streetNum>
        <streetType>RD</streetType>
        <locality>ASHMORE</locality>
        <flatUnitNum />
      <flatUnitType />
        <sitePremisesName />
      </address>
    </addressDetails>
    <communications>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>T</mediumCode>
      <areaCode>07</areaCode>
        <communicationDetails>48103280</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
      <communication>
        <mediumCode>E</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>maryann.smart@dodo.com</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    <communication>
        <mediumCode>M</mediumCode>
        <communicationDetails>0414003242</communicationDetails>
      </communication>
    </communications>
    <registrationDetails>
       <registration>
          <registrationID>NMW0000114235</registrationID>
          <profession>Midwife</profession>
          <division />
          <initialRegistrationStartDate>1994-02-10</initialRegistrationStartDate>
          <registrationType>General</registrationType>
          <registrationSubType />
          <registrationTypeStartDate>1994-02-10</registrationTypeStartDate>
          <registrationStatus>Registered</registrationStatus>
          <registrationStatusStartDate>2011-05-21</registrationStatusStartDate>
          <specialtyDetails>
            <specialtyDetail>
               <specialty />
               <fieldOfSpecialtyPractice />
           <specialtyPracticeStartDate />
           <specialtyPracticeEndDate />
            </specialtyDetail>
          </specialtyDetails>
          <conditionDetails>
            <condition>
               <applicationRegistrationCondition />
               <conditionApprovedDate />
               <conditionDetail />
            </condition>
        </conditionDetails>
        <endorsementDetails>
          <endorsement>
               <endorsementType>Doctor</endorsementType>
               <endorsementSubType>Quack</endorsementSubType>
               <endorsementCreateDate>1999-01-01</endorsementCreateDate>
               <endorsementEndDate>2057-06-06</endorsementEndDate>
          </endorsement>
        </endorsementDetails>
        <undertakingDetails>
          <undertaking>
               <undertakingType>Community Work</undertakingType>
               <undertakingApprovedDate>2002-02-22</undertakingApprovedDate>
               <undertakingText>The Doctor will undertake community work.</undertakingText>
          </undertaking>
        </undertakingDetails>
          <notationDetails>
            <notationDetail>
               <notationCreateDate>2011-02-10</notationCreateDate> 
               <notationEndDate /> 
           <notation>Eligible midwife</notation>
            </notationDetail>
          </notationDetails>
        </registration>
    </registrationDetails>
    <employmentDetails>
      <positionTitle>Doctor Feelgood</positionTitle>
      <sponsorOrganisationName>Motley Crue Morgue</sponsorOrganisationName>
      <sponsorOrganisationContact>Nikki Sixx</sponsorOrganisationContact>
    </employmentDetails>
  </person>
</medicare>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output?

Comment: Hopefully I can work it out from here, but in case you're still keen to be a legend and save me about 6 hours, the output I'm getting is just first or three communication nodes;

Comment: Please edit your original post and add the XSLT you are testing, the real input document and the wanted output.

Comment: -1 for not having presented your solution and having cut off your original question despite so answerers spent a time in helping you.

Comment: Sorry man. Was a genuine newbie mistake and I guess I assumed the history would be preserved. I take your comment on board and I truly appreciated your help. Will rollback last edit and post solution now if I can. Either way I won't repeat this mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assumes you want each mediumCode on a seperate line):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

  <xsl:param name="component"/>

  <xsl:variable name="q" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="', '" />

  <xsl:template match="communication">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$component=4">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($q,../../contactID,$q)" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mediumCode | areaCode | communicationDetails">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($c,$q,.,$q)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contactID" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've created global variables for the commas and the quotes, just to make it a little easier to read in the `concat` function calls.

This stylesheet processes any `communication` element by spitting out the `concatID` of it's `person` ancestor, then just applying templates, which will process it's three child elements.

The next template handles the three child elements in the same way, outputting a comma followed by the value in quotes.

The last template prevents the `contactID` from outputting on it's own. XSLT processors by default will look for a template for every node in your XML tree in sequential order. Without this template present, it'll resort to the default behavior for the text node within it, which is just to output it as is.

If you want all the communication nodes on one line, you can do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

  <xsl:param name="component"/>

  <xsl:variable name="q" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="', '" />

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$component=4">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contactID">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($q,.,$q)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mediumCode | areaCode | communicationDetails">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($c,$q,.,$q)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Here's a solution that produces a consistent number of fields in each row in the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

  <xsl:param name="component"/>

  <xsl:variable name="q" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="', '" />

  <xsl:template match="communication[string-length(concat(mediumCode,areaCode,communicationDetails))!=0]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$component=4">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            $q,../../contactID,$q,$c,
            $q,mediumCode,$q,$c,
            $q,areaCode,$q,$c,
            $q,communicationDetails,$q,'&#xA;'
          )" />
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contactID" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much. Totally exhausted so going to get some sleep. My task has felt a bit like 'Learn Chinese in 2.1 days for Dummy's'. Good on ya guys. You rock

Comment: is funny how XSLT is scary for the "dummies".

Comment: The problem with XSLT compared to conventional languages is that there's no well defined program flow, at least not until you understand how the XSLT processor works. Looking at my examples above, many newcomers to XSLT would be thinking along the lines of 'how the heck does it do anything when you're totally ignoring the `medicare` tag?' for example. Put another way, you don't write your code top down and flesh out the details, you sort out the details first and leave it to the XSLT processor to glue it together for you. It's a very different way of thinking to writing C# etc.

Comment: Hopefully I can work it out from here, but it's still a bit tricky for me. In case you're still keen to be a legend and save me about 6 hours, the output I'm getting is just first or three communication nodes;

"0123456789", "T", "02", "62881111"
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781"

But output I need is;

"0123456789", "T", "02", "62881111"
"0123456789", "E", "",   "john.smith@myisp.com.au"
"0123456789", "M", "",   "04140012225"
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781"
"5290001890", "E", "",   "rabina.smiley@ekit.com"
"5290001890", "M", "",   "04290012333"

Comment: Ah.. I see the problem, you still need 4 fields in each row, even though there's no areaCode element for the last two. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code a bit to avoid iteration. You can get other data just *hard-coding* the index of the `communication` element. I think this is acceptable in your situation. Moreover, I don't know why you are using `normalize-space` function. If you have no multiple spaces in your input document, you could avoid that.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="component" select="4"/>
    <xsl:template match="medicare">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$component=4">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[1]/mediumCode), '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[1]/areaCode), '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;',   
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[1]/communicationDetails), '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[2]/mediumCode), '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[2]/communicationDetails), '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[3]/mediumCode), '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;', 
                normalize-space(communications/
                communication[3]/communicationDetails),'&quot;')" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
"0123456789", "T", "02", "62881111", "E", "john.smith@myisp.com.au", "M", "04140012225"
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781", "E", "rabina.smiley@ekit.com", "M", "04290012333"
```

---

Here follows a cleaner approach which produces the same kind of output (applicable in the case your use case is really close to the data you show in your question):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="component" select="4"/>

    <xsl:template match="medicare">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$component=4">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            '&quot;', contactID, '&quot;', ', ', '&quot;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="communications/communication/*"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="communication/*">  
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&quot;')"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(../following-sibling::communication) + 
            count(following-sibling::*)!=0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat( ', ', '&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much. Totally exhausted so going to get some sleep. My task has felt a bit like 'Learn Chinese in 2.1 days for Dummy's'. Good on ya guys. You rock

Comment: Hopefully I can work it out from here, but it's still a bit tricky for me. In case you're still keen to be a legend and save me about 6 hours, the output I'm getting is just first or three communication nodes;

"0123456789", "T", "02", "62881111"
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781"

But output I need is;

"0123456789", "T", "02", "62881111"
"0123456789", "E", "",   "john.smith@myisp.com.au"
"0123456789", "M", "",   "04140012225"
"5290001890", "T", "02", "92881781"
"5290001890", "E", "",   "rabina.smiley@ekit.com"
"5290001890", "M", "",   "04290012333"

Comment: The output of my transform is exactly as I have shown above. If you need some other kind of output please edit your original post and add the wanted output. Comments are no readable enough for sharing code.